# Cannot use setOnClickListener() and setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()) on TextView

Tags: android, onclick, textview

Hey guys this is my problem. I am trying to be able to click on a `TextView` and detect that touch event (which works if I don't also include the `setMovementMethod`). When I include the `setMovementMethod`, the `onClick` simply does not work at all. I want to use both to be able to scroll down on my `TextView` but also to be able to click on it and handle that event. Thanks.

```
public class SQLView extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_FRONT = "card_front";
    public static final String KEY_BACK = "card_back";
    private Cursor myCursor;
    private TextView tv, card_info;
    private int iRow;
    private int iFront;
    private int iBack;
    private String info = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.flashcard);
        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);

        Flashcards Cards = new Flashcards(this);
        Cards.open();//open DB

        myCursor = Cards.getCursor();

        iRow = myCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        iFront = myCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FRONT);
        iBack = myCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_BACK);

        myCursor.moveToFirst();

        intialize();

        tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
    }

    private void intialize(){

        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_new);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        Button prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);

        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        prev.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.next:
                if(myCursor.isLast()){
                    myCursor.moveToFirst();
                    tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
                }else{
                    myCursor.moveToNext();
                    tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
                }
                break;

            case R.id.prev:

                if(myCursor.isFirst()){

                    myCursor.moveToLast();
                    tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
                }else{
                    myCursor.moveToPrevious();
                    tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
                }
                break;


            case R.id.flashcard:
                if(tv.getText().equals(myCursor.getString(iFront))){
                    tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iBack));
                    break;
                }
                tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
                break;

            case R.id.add_new:
                Intent list = new Intent("com.example.flashcards.ADD_FLASHCARD");
                startActivity(list);
                break;
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/flashcard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.17"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="300"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.51"
        android:text="Add New"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.51"
        android:text="Next"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.51"
        android:text="Previous" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What about your TextView inside a ScrollView ?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a nice class that fixes this for me.

The usage is as such: (textView must contain a link e.g. `click <a href="...">here</a>`

```
ActionableUrlSpan.linkifyTextView(this, textView, new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
   // Do something
 }
});
```

`ActionableUrlSpan` is:

```
public class ActionableUrlSpan extends URLSpan {

    public ActionableUrlSpan(String url) {
        super(url);
    }

    public static void linkifyTextView(Context context, TextView textView,
            final OnClickListener listener) {

        SpannedString spanned = (SpannedString) textView.getText();
        SpannableStringBuilder newSpanned = new SpannableStringBuilder(spanned);

        URLSpan[] spans = newSpanned.getSpans(0, newSpanned.length(), URLSpan.class);
        if (spans.length > 0) {

            URLSpan urlSpan = spans[0];

            int start = newSpanned.getSpanStart(urlSpan);
            int end = newSpanned.getSpanEnd(urlSpan);

            newSpanned.removeSpan(urlSpan);
            newSpanned.setSpan(new ActionableUrlSpan(urlSpan.getURL()) {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onClick(v);

                    super.onClick(v);
                }
            }, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setText(newSpanned);
        } else {
            Log.e("No spans found in url-string " + textView.getText() + " - "
                    + Locale.getDefault());
        }

        MovementMethod m = textView.getMovementMethod();
        if ((m == null) || !(m instanceof LinkMovementMethod)) {
            if (textView.getLinksClickable()) {
                textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call `setFocusable(true)` on your view. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMovementMethod%28android.text.method.MovementMethod%29):

> Be warned that if you want a TextView with a key listener or movement method not to be focusable, or if you want a TextView without a key listener or movement method to be focusable, you must call `setFocusable(boolean)` again after calling this to get the focusability back the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Oleg, but for some reason it did not do anything . I'm still having the exact same issue even with setFocusable(true) on my view. I tried placing it before and after and even calling back the setFocusable().

Comment: Looking into the Android source... have you also tried `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`?

Comment: Yeah I just tried that. It did not work. I guess I will try to find another solution. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Yeah it gets pretty complicated; the Android source implies that click listeners get re-enabled automatically, but eveidently they still don't work.

A solution would be to override `onTouchEvent()` while calling through to `super.onTouchEvent()` and firing your click event when the `event.getAction()` goes from `ACTION_DOWN` to `ACTION_UP` (e.g., keep a boolean state variable).